# .NET Code First Latitude Longitude Interface

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-mapping

I'm developing a database in VB.NET-Code First. I would like to add Latitude and Longitude to both Locations and Postal Codes. Right now i'm adding a GeographicCoordinate to each class.

```
Public Interface ILocation
    Property Street As String
    Property City As ICity
    Property State As IState
    Property Postal_Code As IPostalCode
    Property Country As ICountry
    Property Coordinate As IGeographicCoordinate

Public Interface IPostalCode
    Property ZIP As String
    Property Time_Zone As ITimeZone
    Property Coordinate As IGeographicCoordinate

Public Interface IGeographicCoordinate
    Property Latitude As Decimal
    Property Longitude As Decimal
```

The question I have is would I be better off having the Location and Postal Code inherit the GeographicCoordinate interface instead.  I think with my current implementation I'm going to have a GeographicCoordinates table with at two foreign keys (and likely more for other objects).  If I use the inhearatance implementation I can find the distance between any two IGeographicCoordinate classes...

```
Public Function Distance(byval LHS as IGeographicCoordinate, _
    byval RHS as IGeographicCoordinate)
```

Using the inhearatance implementation would tie both entities in two the implementation of the IGeographicCoordinates.  I could have the classes inherit the GeographicCoordinate class as well...

```
Public Class Location
    Inherits GeographicCoordinate
    Implements ILocation
```

I tend to stay away from doing something like that because i'm locked into not having any classes with lat and long inherit from anything else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I like the way you already have it.  Unless for some reason it is difficult for you to read and write those entities to the database, which it shouldn't be, I think that gives you the most flexibility.  As you said, if you implement the interface on the postal code and location, you can't easily provide coordinate related functionality.  And if you inherit, you limit your ability to inherit form other classes.  So, if the other two options both have down-sides, and your proposed idea doesn't, why not use it?  Unless you can think of some down-side that you didn't mention?